# What is the name of the design style where triangles are drawn in a way that gives a sense of dimension and depth?

Tags: terminology, style

So I have seen this type of graphic design used in several places. Here is an example:

[image: example 1: triangles in the background, text on top]

The exact pattern I am pointing to is how the triangles are drawn in a way that gives a sense of dimension and depth. Here is another example:

[image: example 2: showing only triangles in different colors]

Is there a specific name for this design method?

Comment: That's not quite tessellation, is it?

Comment: Its using the rules of perspective drawing isn't it ?

Comment: I believe it's called faceted design

Comment: It's called **Low poly** it's basically a polygon mesh. It has it's roots in 3D computer graphics that has a relatively small number of polygons.